# Internet Download Manager

Tags: internet, download

I have uninstalled Internet Download Manager from my Computer running on windows 7.
But still in registry search it show about 70 entries that could not be yet removed.
How can I clean it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you have found the correct keys, you may just delete them from the registry after creating a backup.

However, my personal advice is: do not touch your registry unless you really know what you are doing. Assuming from your post, this is not the case. Therefore just leave it as it is, it should not cause any problems. Also, do not install crapware as the "Internet Download Manager" if you want your system to function properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two uninstallers/clean-up utilities available - one [from IDM itself](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/register/new_faq/functions7.html) and the other [here](http://download.chip.eu/en/Internet-Download-Manager-Uninstall_26506814.html). Try both and see if they clear up all remnants of the program. If not, you can manually edit the registry if you know what you're doing and have backups in place.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Revo Uninstaller](http://download.cnet.com/Revo-Uninstaller/3000-2096_4-10687648.html) for issues like these. If the registry entries persist, I've found that reinstalling the offending program, and then uninstalling it with Revo solves the problem, or at least removes the vast majority of entries.

Revo is available for fast install via [ninite](http://ninite.com/).